# xsd validation error when importing

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

We are new users to xsd, and we try to validate a xsd file that needs to import another.
We are trying to do an import from companyInfos.xsd to employmentrecord.xsd. 
Here are the two xsd files we are dealing with.
employmentrecord.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ci="companyInfos.xsd"
    targetNamespace="er" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:import namespace="ci" schemaLocation="companyInfos.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="employment">    
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element type="ci:company"/>
                <xsd:element name="position" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="duration" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="dateStart" type="xsd:date"/>
                <xsd:element name="current" type="xsd:booolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

companyInfos.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="ci" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="company">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="companyName" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="foundationDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                <xsd:element name="field" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="employeeCount" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="logo" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
                <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="httpLink" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>               
</xsd:schema>
```

We got the following error in the terminal when trying the validity:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///home/jiby/Dropbox/ID2208_shared%20with%20JB/SampleParser/ID2208_hw1/xml/employmentrecord.xsd; 
It was detected that 'ci:company' is in namespace 'companyInfos.xsd', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///home/jiby/Dropbox/ID2208_shared%20with%20JB/SampleParser/ID2208_hw1/xml/employmentrecord.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'ci:company' needs to be changed. 
If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///home/jiby/Dropbox/ID2208_shared%20with%20JB/SampleParser/ID2208_hw1/xml/employmentrecord.xsd'.

(I don't know if it can be useful, but here are the two xml files)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="er"
            xmlns:ci="companyInfos.xsd"
       >
     <ci:company>
            <companyName>
                Google
            </companyName>
            <foundationDate>
                1995-09-15
            </foundationDate>
            <field>
                Search engine
            </field>
            <employeeCount>
                40000
            </employeeCount>
            <logo>
                http://static3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100520131748/logopedia/images/5/5c/Google_logo.png
            </logo>
            <description>
                Google is an American multinational corporation specializing in Internet-related services and products. These include search, cloud computing, software, and online advertising technologies
            </description>
    </ci:company>
    <position>Chief Finantial Opportunist</position>
    <duration>1 year</duration>
    <dateStart>2012-01-01</dateStart>
    <current>false</current>
</employment>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="ci">
    <companyName>
        Google
    </companyName>
    <foundationDate>
        1995-09-15
    </foundationDate>
    <field>
        Search engine
    </field>
    <employeeCount>
        40000
    </employeeCount>
    <logo>
        http://static3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100520131748/logopedia/images/5/5c/Google_logo.png
    </logo>
    <description>
        Google is an American multinational corporation specializing in Internet-related services and products. These include search, cloud computing, software, and online advertising technologies
    </description>
    <httpLink>http://google.com</httpLink>
</company>
```

We tried to look on the forums for an answer but the proposed solutions didn't seem to work, the file always had some issues for validation.

Comment: Just a guess, but wouldn't you need to define `ci:company` as `<xsd:element ref="ci:company" />` as you are referring to an already defined type?

Comment: We had this mistake with this one:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///Users/kevin/Dropbox/ID2208_shared%20with%20JB/SampleParser/ID2208_hw1/xml/employmentrecord.xsd; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 40; s4s-att-not-allowed : The attribute 'typeref' must not figure in the element 'element'.

Comment: Not sure what your problems are exactly, referencing elements from an imported schema works in our case pretty well. Maybe have a look at [this link here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between namespace prefixes and namespace URIs. The namespace attribute of xs:importSchema and the targetNamespace attribute of xs:schema should both be URIs, and they should match. You should also bind a prefix to this URI and use this prefix in any references to names from the imported schema namespace.